# Magento: How to save data to order_payment and quote_payment

Tags: magento

I'm trying to have a custom credit card payment attribute save to two different tables but I'm not sure how to do this.

The normal credit card information saves to two different tables.

- sales_flat_quote_payment
- sales_flat_order_payment

I created the new attribute and it should be saved to both tables. The column with the correct value has been set on both tables but it only saves to one "sales_flat_quote_payment" right when the customer places the order.

How can I make it so it saves the data to both tables?

I found this reference but I'm not sure how to implemente it to make it work with a credit card attribute value.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19344/P0/

Can anyone confirm if this would work?

```
    <sales_copy_order_payment>
        <cc_bankname>
        <to_order>*</to_order>
        </cc_bankname>
    </sales_copy_order_payment>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure Magento to convert the new attribute from quote to order? If you check the `config.xml` from the `Mage_Sales` module and search for `sales_convert_quote_payment`. You see something as follows:

```
       <sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <method><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></method>
            <additional_data><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></additional_data>
            <additional_information><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></additional_information>
            <po_number><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></po_number>
            <cc_type><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_type>
            <cc_number_enc><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_number_enc>
            <cc_last4><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_last4>
            <cc_owner><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_owner>
            <cc_exp_month><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_exp_month>
            <cc_exp_year><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_exp_year>

            <cc_number><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_number>
            <cc_cid><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_cid>

            <cc_ss_issue><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_ss_issue>
            <cc_ss_start_month><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_ss_start_month>
            <cc_ss_start_year><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></cc_ss_start_year>
        </sales_convert_quote_payment>
```

Magento uses these `fieldsets` to transport data from entity to entity. In this case from the `quote_payment` to the `order_payment`.

Since all config XML is merged into one big heap of XML, you can add additional nodes from your own modules config.xml. Something like:

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_payment>
            <your_attribute><to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment></your_attribute>
        </sales_convert_quote_payment>
    </fieldsets>
</global>
```

Hope this helps you get underway.

Comment: Thank you. I had previously overriden the mage/sales module but I have no idea why the config file that was located on the sales module was not the correct one. After looking at yours and your refernce, I copied the config.xml file again and edited the necessary fields.

Unfortunately, I'll have to wait until the morning to confirm if it worked or not.

I appreciate your help, I'll give more feedback in the morning.

Comment: Alright, I tested it by adding the attribute to the config.xml file and it didn't work. I made sure it was documented properly but the value is not copied over to the sales_flat_order_payment table.